# Generating function within a generating function

Tags: combinatorics

I have the problem:

Bags of candy are being prepared to distribute to the children at a school. The types of candy available are chocolate bites, peanut butter cups, peppermint candies, and fruit chews. Each bag must contain at least two chocolate bites, an even number of peanut butter cups, and at most six peppermint candies. The fruit chews are available in four different flavors—lemon, orange, strawberry, and cherry. A bag of candy may contain at most two fruit chews, which may be of the same or different flavors. Beyond the number of pieces of each type of candy included, bags of candy are distinguished by using the flavors of the fruit chews included, not just the number. For example, a bag containing two orange fruit chews is different from a bag containing a cherry fruit chew and a strawberry fruit chew, even if the number of pieces of each other type of candy is the same.

And I'm trying to find a formula for number of bags with $n$ pieces of candy, for which I'm trying to use a generating function which I get as follows:

$(x^2+x^3+x^4+...)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+...)(1+x+x^2+...+x^6)$

But I'm confused at the part with the fruit chews.  I feel like that would be it's own generating function that looks like $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4+x_5=2$ so $x^2$ in $(1 + x + x^2 + ...)^5$, but I don't know how to combine that with the generating function for the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we just consider the fruit chews. The exponents have to match the actual number of candies, but the coefficients don’t have to be $1$: we can do some of the counting in the process of assembling the generating function.

Each bag can have $0,1$, or $2$ of them. There is only way for a bag to have $0$ fruit chews. There are $4$ different ways for a bag to have exactly $1$ fruit chew, one for each flavor. And there are $4+\binom42=10$ different ways for a bag to have exactly $2$ fruit chews, $4$ with two of the same flavor and $6$ with two of different flavors. This situation is described by the polynomial $1+4x+10x^2$. Now just combine that suitably with what you already have.